# multitouch events in javascript not firing

Tags: javascript, android, html5-canvas, android-canvas, multi-touch

Go to any online multitouch javascript demo page; here are some:
[mdn](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events%24samples/Example?revision=493243) (same as jsfiddle.net/Darbicus/z3Xdx/10/) or [this](http://openbox.ir/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/touch.htm). I can only post max 2 links but every online multitouch demo i could find has same behaviour as described here.

Put one finger on canvas and don't move or release it. Now put another finger on canvas and try to draw some shape by moving it (be careful not to make movement with first finger). It doesn't draw shape, touchmove event is not happening for 2nd touch! Don't release any finger yet. Try to move only first finger. Now you get touchmove event for both fingers at once and all events work fine (immediately) for both touches from now on.

I tested it on 2 different tablets with Android 4.2.2. On both tablets i tested it first with Chrome 31 and 32 and then with Firefox 26. Always same result.

Why is touchmove event not firing for second touch if first touch hasn't moved yet? How to solve this?

Comment: Make sure to call preventDefault on touchmove so the platform keeps providing the events http://htmlblog.mabedan.com/post/74054336215/touchmove-events-handling-difference-between-android

Comment: This doesn't work. In meantime i found out that Google fixed this behaviour in latest Chrome beta version 33 (https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=244063&view=revision), i tested it and it works perfectly. But in latest stable versions of Firefox and Opera there is still problem. Let's hope they fix it soon too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google fixed this behaviour in latest Chrome beta version 33 (https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=244063&view=revision)

Firefox and Opera still have this problem.